# how to send a static file when nginx proxy 302 redirect

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-302

I have server that implements a 302 redirect to server some content.

for example when user request `http://a.com/images/a.jpg`, my server will make a request to `server B: http://b.com/images/a.jpg`, but `server B` may be return 302. so what I want is when `server B` return 302, my server will send a `a.logo` to user.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.com;
     location / {
      proxy_pass http://www.girls-av.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_cache nginx-cache;
       proxy_cache_valid 200 302 304 1440m;
       proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 301 302 = @handler;
   }
    location @handler {
       proxy_pass /home/git/a/images/logo.png;   
   }
}

// but I got an error "invalid URL prefix"
```

then I try

```
location @handler {
 proxy_pass http://a.com/images/logo.png;   
}

// but I got this error ""proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location"
```

and I also try

```
location @handler {
  alias /home/git/a/images/logo.png;   
}
// but I got another error the "alias" directive cannot be used inside the named location;
```

What sholud I do, anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this:

```
server {             
    listen 80;
    server_name a.com; 
    # ...

    error_page 301 302 = @handler;          
    location @handler {                   
       root /tmp/logo;                    
       try_files /logo.png /dev/null =404;
       error_log /tmp/nginx-error.log debug;                                         
    }                
}
```

The file `logo.png`, in this case, is in `/tmp/logo/logo.png`

For testing only notice the:

```
error_log /tmp/nginx-error.log debug;
```

Comment: it didn't work, when user request `a.com/a/b/c.jpg`, it will try to return `/tmp/logo/a/b/c.jpg` not `tmp/logo/logo.png`

Comment: did you set `try_files $uri /logo.png =404;` notice the `/logo.png` I just tested and works

Comment: I just try to use `try_files /tmp/log/logo.png`, it works now.

Comment: nice :-) what version of Nginx are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.10.2

Comment: I updated the answer with a workaround `try_files /logo.png /dev/null =404;` just in case